# Cannot resolve method stream() issue

Tags: java, java-stream

I am currently learning about streams in java, but when i try to  write some simple code like this

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
       map.put("Tom", 5);
       map.put("Andrew", 6);
       map.put("Kim", 3);
       map.put("Milo", 2);

       map.stream();
```

it gives me `java cannot resolve method stream()`
I am using Inttelij and coding in java 11 and I honestly don't know what is going on.

Comment: `Map` has no `stream` method. Perhaps you want to stream over the entrySet? `map.entrySet().stream()`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know aobut that. It solved my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description):

> Streams can be obtained in a number of ways. Some examples include:
>
> - From a Collection via the stream() and parallelStream() methods;
> - From an array via Arrays.stream(Object[]);
> - From static factory methods on the stream classes, such as Stream.of(Object[]), IntStream.range(int, int) or Stream.iterate(Object, UnaryOperator);
> - The lines of a file can be obtained from BufferedReader.lines();
> - Streams of file paths can be obtained from methods in Files;
> - Streams of random numbers can be obtained from Random.ints();
> - Numerous other stream-bearing methods in the JDK, including BitSet.stream(), Pattern.splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence), and JarFile.stream().

Since the `Map` doesn't implement `Collection` interface, it doesn't fit any of these ways and means doesn't have `stream()` method. But you could use stream with:

```
map.keySet().stream();
map.values().stream();
map.entrySet().stream();
```

Comment: "Since the Map isn't a collection" just to be precise: Map is a *collection* (in general term as it collects elements), but it isn't subtype of `java.util.Collection` which methods ware designed for handling single elements (like `add(element)`) but it didn't provide methods for handling pairs of elements like Map does (for example `put(key,value)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use bellow code:

```
map.entrySet().stream().forEach(item->{
            System.out.println(item.getKey()+" "+item.getValue());
        });
```